# How to make resharper to recognize JSon as incorrect abbreviation

Tags: resharper, naming-conventions, abbreviation, resharper-8.0

One of my colleagues likes to spell `Json` in identifiers as `JSon`.

How can I make Resharper to detect that `JSon` is an incorrect abbreviation and to suggest valid spelling?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ReSharper plug-in https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/ReSpeller/

Comment: This plug-in by default threats `Json` as incorrect word and suggests to replace it with "Jason", "Son" or "Jon".

Anyway, the plug-in doesn't prevent me from entering `JSon`